# How to Plot this kind of data in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

My data is here --

```
  0.000              0              0    
  0.001            104             51
  0.002            202            101
  0.003            298            148
  0.0031           290            149
  0.004            289            201
  0.0041           291            209
  0.005            310            250
  0.010            311            260
  0.020            280            240
```

Now **how can I plot this data in Gnuplot?** As far as I know, I have to create a ***dat*** file. But I am not sure about it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Have you checked the manual and basic gnuplot tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, such basic operation is actually not the idea of StackOverflow. Please consult some tutorial and have a look at the examples on the gnuplot homepage.

Nevertheless, in short: you don't have to create a file you can provide the data in the code as a datablock.

**Code:**

```
### very basic plot from datablock
reset session

$Data <<EOD
  0.000              0              0    
  0.001            104             51
  0.002            202            101
  0.003            298            148
  0.0031           290            149
  0.004            289            201
  0.0041           291            209
  0.005            310            250
  0.010            311            260
  0.020            280            240
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7, \
       ''  u 1:3 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, say thank you by accepting the answer and your question will appear as answered.